# Getting payment information from outside magento as on order view page

Tags: orders, payment

I want to get the payment information for the related payment method as in the order view page "payment information" tab. I want to run custom query outside Magento to get these information.

Comment: Any movement on this? Anything I can do to help clarify an answer for you? Please update your question if you have more information that can help us close this out.

Answer (score 3):

I highly suggest you **don't do this the way you plan**. Specifically, don't create a standalone script that will take an order number and output a formatted payment block.

Rather, use the API. Safeguard "public" access to it. Don't hardcode the API user/password.

The reasons for using the API are numerous, but the most obvious to me is security. By using the API you will be making requests with an API User granted specific privileges. If you do **not** use the API you will rely on your own abilities as a programmer to safeguard against compromising your customers' security - and the information you're requesting is specifically payment information.

So I'll tell you how to access it via the SOAP v2 (warning: contrived example, do not hardcode user/pass directly in your publicly accessible scripts):

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://yourmagentourl.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); 

$result = $proxy->salesOrderInfo($sessionId, '200000006');
```

Your payment info is now available in `$result['payment']`. 
Of course this will not format the output as the payment block. To do so we can format it manually:

```
<?php $payment = $result['payment']; ?>
<table>
    <thead/>
    <tfoot/>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Type:</td><td><?php echo $payment['cc_type']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last 4:</td><td><?php echo $payment['cc_last4']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CC Owner:</td><td><?php echo $payment['cc_owner']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

More information on what's available in the sales order/payment API:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html

Comment: I am getting this error, I think my path is not correct for soap, how to find the correct path for magento 1.7. SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://blackstarserver.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1' : Extra content at the end of the document

Comment: A quick google helps http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/56528/  || additionally this is not an error with my answer but perhaps an outdated PHP version. See the link for more details.